"You ˹alone˺ we ask for help." - what does it mean in the Quran?
What should we do if we need help of beings other than Allah in necessary situations?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please take your time to write a clear concise question adding all relevant information like the verse you refer to etc.. Please take into consideration: every being that might help you was created by Allah how can anyone else help without HIM being involved?

Someone wants help about an issue, and thinks/believes the solution to that issue should be through a specified way, and so decides to go for that way. It might be the case that the person is misjudging the issue altogether, or misidentify the solution, or mistakenly assume the way that appears to be the correct way for his goal to be really so. Therefore, a Muslim is always expected to recall that only Allah knows everything, only He is capable of doing anything, and that only He knows what is good for us or bad, irrespective of if we would like it or not. Therefore, a Muslim does anything that comes to his mind and seems correct to him, whether through studying the issue and thinking about it, or consulting by those who we think they might know something about, or else, and at last, ask for help from Allah that all effects are from Him.
Once people asked Imam Ali PBUH how did he know Allah? Imam PBUH answered back through decision makings, every time I decided to do something, something else happened, and so I understand that a greater will runs in between, a will that runs beyond my will. So that you ask help from a physician, but the drug has not the effect it was considered to be so, and no one knew it previously, and something else happens that helps you achieve what you were looking for, and you may call it a rare accident, while it is not and the universe does not run by chance.
A Muslim knows anything that has (or seems to have, based on what we have learned all these years through our own experiences, or others) an effect, that effect is from Allah, and Allah can cause that thing to have different effects, like the fire that tuned to be non-burning but even pleasant for Ibrahim PBUH. Ask help from anyone you like but don't forget Allah and that no one can help you if Allah wants the otherwise, and that something that you may not take serious might become your ultimate solution if Allah wants it this way.
Monotheism has three levels, the first is that there is not god but only Allah (توحید ذاتی), the next level is that Allah's attributions are not shared with anyone else (توحید صفاتی), and the last one is to know every effect is from Allah, even if you see it happen through other means (توحید افعالی).
